# Add UIView over UIViewImage. Users can zooming image

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to add UIView over my UIImage. But it doesn't work for me.
When I reduce and increase my image, UIView moved down and doesn't cover completely my image.
[image]

I use double click for zooming.

```
@objc func doubleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if self.productScrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
        self.productScrollView.zoom(to: self.zoomRectForScale(scale: self.productScrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)), animated: true)
    } else {
        self.productScrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }

}
```

I tried to use these codes, but it doesn't work for me.

1. first:

   ```
    let tintView = UIView()
    tintView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    tintView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, 
    height: imageView.frame.height)
    imageView.addSubview(tintView)
   ```
2. Second:

   ```
   let tintView = UIView()
   tintView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
   tintView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   imageView.addSubview(tintView)
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           tintView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor),
           tintView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor),
           tintView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor),
           tintView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor),
           ])
   ```

also, I tried to add on storyboard, but it also doesn't work for me.
Does anyone have ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your UIView to the main view of your viewController instead of UIImageView and set constraints to the imageView